# Boot Repair Disk: unable to access dpkg status area in Debian

Tags: linux, boot, debian, grub, bootrepair

I have a machine with two physical hard drives and `Debian 9` on one of them. A couple of weeks ago I replaced thermal paste in there and it stopped booting. After some time of troubleshooting I found out that I messed up with one of my hard drive's connection and fixed it. Unfortunately, it did not solve the problem.

As for now I have `Boot Repair Disk` installed on third internal drive. When I try to start to repair boot it asks me to run `sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda2" dpkg --configure -a` in terminal and does nothing more. The command above produces the following error `dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: No such file or directory`.

**Here's partition table reported by `GParted`:**

[image: Partition table on /dev/sda]

[image: Partition table on /dev/sdb]

**Here's available options in `Boot Repair Disk`:**

[image: Boot Repair Disk configuration and error]

What is wrong with `dpkg` in this case and how can I repair boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. Originally `/var` was mounted on a separate partition. The key to success was to mount `/dev/sda3` as `/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/var`.